# Displaying Japanese fonts in source code using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have some source files that have comments written in Japanese. When I open these files in Visual Studio they appear like this:

```
à–¾FNCAP‰¹—p‚ÌƒXƒŒƒbƒh
```

I am using the English version of WinXP, but is there a way to get Visual Studio to display the actual Japanese characters rather than the random jibberish it currently is?

Comment: If you're using Source Safe, make a manual backup of your code with the Japanese text immediately.  Unicode can corrupt files in VSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably VS is interpreting the file with the wrong encoding.

Reopen it using "File -> Open -> File... -> Open -> Open With... -> Source Code (Text) Editor With Encoding" and try various encodings.

Comment: That works for one off case, but not if you are doing general development work where you open files all the time. Every time it asks you for the charset >:-(

Comment: Yeah, I'm faced with the same issue. I was able to open a single file with various encodings and in this way I discovered the correct one. I'm just unsure of how I inform Visual Studio to open source files for an entire solution in said encoding.

Answer (score 6):

I found a general solution to the problem. This worked for me in Chinese text for Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 8.1.

per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246590.aspx

1. As Administrator Click Start, click Control Panel, and then open Regional and Language Options (or Region in Windows 8).
2. Click the Advanced tab. (or Administrative in Windows 8)
3. In the Select a language to match the language version of the non-Unicode programs you want to use list, select the language you are currently using.
4. Click OK.

Comment: in my case this did not help me, i had to do this :[Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-East-Asian-fonts-in-Windows-10-for-use-with-Office-documents-d3db3730-3674-4a53-bfb9-1a8533524fba)

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on support for Eastern languages for Windows?  I have that turned on and I can see Chinese characters in Visual Studio 2005 on WinXP.

To turn it on you'll probably need the installation DVD for Windows.  The setting is under Regional and Language Options in the Control Panel.  I think you just need to check the "Install files for East Asian languages" option.

[Microsoft's support page for internationalization](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/handson/user/xpintlsupp.mspx) has some screenshots and instructions.

Comment: That link appears to be defunct.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and have found a solution that works for me.

The problem is that the files aren't unicode and VS is trying to open them with an encoding that matches your location. Luckily, you can set Windows default behavior for non-unicode files. Check out this link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246590.aspx. Look under "To correctly display characters that are not included in the current code page."

These directions are incorrect for Windows 8 (I can't speak for 7 or older.) For Windows 8:

1. Navigate to Control Panel
2. Select Clock, Language, and Region (yeah they still have the comma before and)
3. Region
4. Administrative
5. Change System Locale...
6. Select the desired language from the "Current System Locale" drop down

Most of your programs should continue to function in English as this setting is only applied when programs and files don't support unicode.

Answer (score 0):

i have just gotten this problem and fixed it by changing config "files.encoding" in file "setting.json" . Go to Menu => File => Reference => setting to open the file. Search for "files.encoding" and change value to Encoding of your file (my file encoded in Shift-JIS , i checked ending by using Notpad++)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 : --> Control Panel\Clock and Region\Region

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the text encoding to UTF-8 using Notepad++.

1. Originally encoded as Shift-JIS:

   [image: image1]
2. Convert to UTF-8:

   [image: image2]
3. Save file.

It should now display correctly regardless of local region.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encoding file to UTF-8 BOM (not UTF-8) in Notepad++. After that, you can use your file in visual studio. It's work for me.