# How to show Chinese character in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem when showing the Chinese character in vs 2012. When I try to show them, they only show  (square symbol). How can I show it it visual studio 2012. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: with 'show' you mean in the editor or in the program you're debugging?

Comment: I doubt this is what your looking for: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30681 but it can't hurt.

Comment: check this link [Visual-studio-2010-to-show-chinese-comments-properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776661/how-can-i-get-visual-studio-2010-to-show-chinese-comments-properly)

Comment: To Wouter Huysentruit : yes, when we were debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Set up font in studio that has chinese symbols.

Comment: I can solve the problem by add more Chinese language in Control Panel. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use applocale, download it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13209.

This is an old app but works well on Win7 and Win8 (tested). When installing, simply make sure to run it as admin. Then later on, run devnev.exe (visual studio) using applocale and set the locale to Chinese. I just tested this works perfectly well.