# JavaScript changing Japanese text to broken characters in .js file

Tags: javascript

I have a .js file that contains some Japanese characters, when I load the .js file in my IDE(visual studio code) then the characters appear broken.

Here is the file (with messed up characters already)

```
//���x�����v���_�E����e�ύX
function autoloan(){
    $(".lastpaymentform").hide();
    document.form1.plan.value = 1;
    document.getElementById("installments_desc").innerHTML = "���x������"; // ���x������ ���o���ύX
    document.getElementById("bpmaxrate").innerHTML = "50"; // �{�[�i�X���Z�z �A�������ύX
```

What is causing this and how do I fix it? It is breaking my web apps when I try to use it.

Comment: It's not a JavaScript issue but has to do with the chosen text encoding. Your IDE might assume a different encoding when the text is actually e.g. UTF-8 etc.

Comment: What do you mean with `is breaking my web apps`? Do you get a syntax error for the script or does the script work and displays those garbage instead if japanes letters?

Comment: Do you have the Japanese language pack installed on your PC?

Comment: the script works but displays garbage characters. The confusing part for me is that I also have some japanese in my html but is displays normally.

Comment: This might help ► https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210547/displaying-japanese-fonts-in-source-code-using-visual-studio